# Why Promise.all is not bound to Promise?

Tags: javascript

Having these nested functions:

```
Promise.all( mapDomains( x => x.close() ) )
```

I thought about composing them:

```
compose(Promise.all, mapDomains)( x => x.close() )
```

However the code above fails without binding Promise.all to itself. This is the fix:

```
let f1 = Promise.all.bind(Promise)
compose(f1, mapDomains)( x => x.close() )
```

Although I understand it is all about how the `this` keyword works in Javascript, I wonder: Why is `.all` not bounded to itself already? Is there any value on that?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something like this is the problem:

```js
var Promise = {
  all: function() {
    console.log(this.text)
  },
  text: 'some text'
};

Promise.all(); //some text

function compose(f) {
  f(); //Here 'this' will not be what you expect, unless you've bound it
}

compose(Promise.all); //undefined
compose(Promise.all.bind(Promise)); //some text
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use it with another Promise implementation

```js
// just a demo
// this should be another library to make sense
class MyPromise extends Promise { 
  then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
    const wrappedOnFulfilled = function(arg) {
       console.log(`I was fulfilled with ${arg}`)
       return onFulfilled(arg)
    }
    return super.then.call(this, wrappedOnFulfilled, onRejected)
  }
}

var all = Promise.all

const myPromise = all
  .call(MyPromise, [MyPromise.resolve(1), MyPromise.resolve(2)])
  .then(([x,y]) => console.log(x, y))

console.log(myPromise instanceof MyPromise)
```